# How to make an "AsyncLazy" primitive/wrapper with an `async get` and a sync `getOrNil`?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I have a situation where I need to compute something at-most-once. This value is computed asynchronously but also needs to be available without `await`-ing. If the value isn't computed, then `nil` is fine. Basically, the following protocol:

```
/// A value that is computed at most once. The value is asynchronously
/// computed the first time it's accessed.
public protocol AsyncLazy<T> where T : Sendable {
  associatedtype T

  /// The value, or nil if it hasn't been fetched yet.
  var valueOrNil: T? { get }

  /// The value, once it is computed
  var value: T { get async }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
val someValue = AsyncLazyImpl { someComputation() }

...

// On main thread...
let x = someValue.valueOrNil

// On other threads...
let x = await someValue.value
```

How would I implement this? I'm lost trying to make sense of what locks and concurrency primitives I'd use.

Comment: “On main thread”, do you mean MainActor?

Comment: Yes, but MainActor runs on main thread so why the distinction?

Comment: Yeah, but the converse is not always true. Also, I assume you meant `let`, not `val`. And I assume you don’t really mean “lazy” (which has a very different meaning).

Comment: @CalebJares strictly speaking the MainActor only guarantees that code running in its context will not be running currently with any other MainActor code.  The OS is free to schedule execution on any thread so long as it can guarantee that no other MainActor code is running concurrently.  It doesn't have to be the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that `someComputation` is slow, synchronous, and does not explicitly `yield` during the calculation. If so, that means we have to get it out of the Swift concurrency system. In WWDC 2022 video [Visualize and optimize Swift concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110350/?time=1186), Apple says:

> If you have code that needs to [perform slow, synchronous functions that cannot periodically yield to the Swift concurrency system], move that code outside of the concurrency thread pool – for example, by running it on a dispatch queue – and bridge it to the concurrency world using continuations. Whenever possible, use async APIs for blocking operations to keep the system operating smoothly.

So, with the above caveat in mind, you theoretically could do something like:

```swift
@MainActor
class AsyncValue<T: Sendable> {
    private var task: Task<T, Never>!
    
    private(set) var currentValue: T?
    
    init(block: @Sendable @escaping () -> T) {
        task = Task {
            let value = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    let result = block()
                    continuation.resume(returning: result)
                }
            }
            currentValue = value
            return value
        }
    }
    
    func asynchronousValue() async -> T {
        return await task.value
    }
}
```

Generally, combining GCD with Swift concurrency is a mistake, but given the constraints of the original question, this is an exception to the rule.

Please note that this is not a generalized solution, but a straw-man that is narrowly answering your question. A few observations:

1. I have isolated this whole thing to the main actor so that you can fetch the `currentValue` (what you called `valueOrNil`) from there without awaiting. (If you were only invoking this from asynchronous Swift concurrency contexts, you could instead just make this an `actor`.)
2. I have supplied an `asynchronousValue` function (which is analogous to the `value` property in your example) that awaits the `Task` that was initiated when the `AsyncValue` was instantiated.
3. Be forewarned that this just launches a task on a global queue (which is subject to the thread-explosion risks that plague legacy GCD code, namely, if you created lots of these objects). You should consider using a static serial queue, or operation queue with some reasonable `maxConcurrentOperationCount` or the like.

   Also note that this is non-cancellable.

---

Having illustrated a possible solution, I would consider this an anti-pattern, because we generally strive to:

- remain entirely within the Swift concurrency system;
- avoid unstructured concurrency; and
- support cancelation handling.

I would encourage you to reevaluate the situation in which you contemplated using this pattern, and see if there might be some more idiomatic Swift concurrency approach.